# How to mapping restful api in react app via bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, card, bootstrap-cards

I want to consume restful api in react application via bootstrap. But I can't mapping correctly. I believe that the problem is brackets. But I couldn't figure out. (ignore my div part if I can mapping, I will update that part.)

My restful api: https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json

Restful api Json formatted:

```
{
   "time":{
      "updated":"Jun 2, 2022 08:38:00 UTC",
      "updatedISO":"2022-06-02T08:38:00+00:00",
      "updateduk":"Jun 2, 2022 at 09:38 BST"
   },
   "disclaimer":"This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
   "chartName":"Bitcoin",
   "bpi":{
      "USD":{
         "code":"USD",
         "symbol":"&#36;",
         "rate":"29,941.3155",
         "description":"United States Dollar",
         "rate_float":29941.3155
      },
      "GBP":{
         "code":"GBP",
         "symbol":"&pound;",
         "rate":"23,980.6882",
         "description":"British Pound Sterling",
         "rate_float":23980.6882
      },
      "EUR":{
         "code":"EUR",
         "symbol":"&euro;",
         "rate":"28,094.2357",
         "description":"Euro",
         "rate_float":28094.2357
      }
   }
}
```

My App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Lists from './example/lists';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Lists lists={this.state.lists} />
        )
    }

    state = {
        lists: {}
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({ lists: data })
            })
            .catch(console.log)
    }
}

export default App;
```

My list.js:

```
import React from 'react'

const Lists = ({lists}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <center><h1>Exchange</h1></center>
            {lists.map((list) => (
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{list.time}</h5>
                        <h5 class="card-title">{list.bpi}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
};

export default Lists
```

Comment: you can only use map on array of objects and your api is returning just object

Comment: @AmanSadhwani can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

The json is not an array therefore no you do not need to `map` through it. Remove the map from the List component.

```
import React from 'react'

const Lists = ({lists}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <center><h1>Exchange</h1></center>
           
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">{lists.time}</h5>
                      <h5 class="card-title">{lists.bpi}</h5>
                  </div>
               </div>
        
        </div>
    )
};

export default Lists
```

Comment: `./src/components/list.js  Line 9:  'list' is not defined  no-undef Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.` When I delete the map. I'm getting this error.

Comment: thats because the name of the variable has changed to "lists" not "list" as it now references the prop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your json is complete but, since your json is returning an object, you cannot use map or any loop. You just need to display the data without looping

Comment: When I remove the map part Im getting this error: ` ./src/components/list.js  Line 9:  'list' is not defined  no-undef Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.`

Comment: Yeah you can't use map for an object. so in your case. you just display each object value directly to your jsx.